# Sliding window cnn

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, sliding-window

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 16, initial_epoch=10,epochs=15, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
```

I have trained a model using LeNet architecture for some symbol images. I have to detect these symbols using sliding window cnn algorithm on different img. How can I do that?
Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.predict()` function on the test dataset for prediction.
Like this:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I want to detect symbol in different img using sliding window cnn algo which I have trained using this model. How can I do that?

Comment: @ShreyasNatu First, apply the preprocessing techniques on your image (the same ones you applied on your training images), then reshape it to the required input shape of the model and use `model.predict()` function to get the prediction

Comment: How can apply sliding window algo here?